# Largest interval containing family of sets with an overlap property

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, additive-combinatorics

Here's a simplified version of a question I'm interested in.

Given $p$ and $q$ distinct prime numbers, we consider sets $A\subset \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}, 0\in A$ of size $pq$, which are uniformly distributed $\mod p$ and $\mod q$.

I'm looking for the largest natural number $N$ such that any set $A$ with the properties above, and which is contained in the interval $[0,N]$ will satisfy the following: there exists a point $x$ and a unique element $a_0\in A$ (which might depend on $x$) such that
$$
x-a\in A-A 
$$
whenever $a\in A\setminus\{a_0\}$.

Nontrivial lower\upper bounds are also of interest.

Perhaps to give an explicit example of such, we can think of $p=2, q=3$, $A=\{0,4,5,9,11,16 \}$ and the point $x=7$.

Comment: What are some (trivial?) upper and lower bounds you can come up with? Can you motivate the question further?

Comment: @kodlu As far as motivation, one may think of the point $x$ satisfying the property in the question as signifying a location such that the only way to cover it by a translated copy of $A$ which does not overlap $A$ itself, is by placing that copy at $x-a_0$. I'm afraid I can't give further reference.


For an upper bound, one can take $N$ large enough so that any natural number can be expressed as the sum of 3 distinct elements of $A$ in at most one way. I didn't work out the exact value of $N$.


I don't have a meaningful lower bound.